# Take local XAMPP online

Tags: windows-7, webserver, xampp

### Current scenario:

---

I am running windows 7 behind a router and have installed XAMPP. Multiple computers connect to this internet connection.

I have port forwarded the ports 80,8080 and 443 on the router for my internal (local) ip address (192.168.x.x)

*additional info:* my current internet plan provides me with 2 public ip addresses

### What I want to achieve:

---

- I would like to access my XAMPP
  server when I type my public (static)
  IP address in my web browser. I
  thought port forwarding ought to have
  done the trick. But that didn't solve
  anything.
- Also if I have multiple XAMPP
  instances on different computers on
  the same local network setup how do I
  get them online or rather access them
  online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps may be very system/router dependent. But here is the general approach I used:

1. Using your router configuration page, forward port 80 to your machine's IP address.
2. Register for a service like DynDNS so that you have a static text <-> dynamic IP mapping (you can use john.dyndns.org or something that will always point to your dynamic IP)
3. Use some sort of client that will keep the dyndns servers updated about your dynamically changing IP address. Many routers themselves come with a feature to do this for standard services like dyndns. But if you don't have one, you can download a client from their website.

Now, whenever you use your dyndns URL that you choose when  registering (john.dyndns.org or something), from anywhere, the request will be seent to your dynamic IP which is kept track by dyndns and then after reaching your firefall/router, will be forwarded to your machine, where your XAMPP can process it. If all goes well, you can get the whole thing working in an hour max.

**Important**
Once you have all things setup, if you simply try out your domain name or your dyndns URL from any system within your LAN, you will only get to see your router page. For it to work properly, you should try to access your web server from OUTSIDE your LAN. So do that, or use a proxy. I forgot the reason for this :|

Also, if you need to access the XAMPP from within the LAN, simply get the LAN IP of the XAMPP system and use it from within your LAN.

Comment: @Senthil - i have a public aka static ip address, so I hope that I don't have to use DynDNS. I have already port forwarded port 80, 8080 and 443. I still can't achieve what I want as I can still see my routers page when I type my IP. so what else should I do?

Comment: When you say you can still see your routers page, are you trying it from your own system - the same system where XAMPP is?

Comment: @Senthil -Actually I have linked an A record using my public IP address to a domain I own, and I'm trying link that to my XAMPP server. Now when I type that domain in my web-browser I get my router page. And I have tried accessing it from another computer to the same result.

Comment: If you try it from your system it will not work. Try it from a computer outside your lan. Or use a proxy like swifttunnel.com or something. IT will work. For some reason which I cannot remember, when port forwarding your web server, if you try it from within the same system where your server is, you will only get to see your router page. So try it from outside your LAN or use a proxy to see it. Go to swifttunnel.com and type your domain name. You web server will show up :)

Comment: Okay neat it does show up from a proxy site! How can I see it from my LAN? will I always have to go via proxy?

Comment: I am afraid I have forgotten if it is possible and if so, how. I will post back if I can find out how. Meanwhile, your setup as such works and XAMPP is available online. I am guessing you will have more visitors from outside your LAN than inside? :D

Comment: @Senthil - okay cool I'll wait for your reply until then

Comment: You can simply use the LAN IP of the XAMPP system (192.168.1.2, 1.3, 1.4 etc..) Find the one for the system with XAMPP and use it from anywhere within your LAN.

Comment: I know that, but I was hoping to access it via my domain. I think I'll just edit the hosts file. The only problem is that I won't know when my page is offline, because of some inconstancy with my XAMPP server